# when developing using eclipse or netbeans, do you use phpmyadmin to admin mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, netbeans

When developing using eclipse or NetBeans, do you use phpmyadmin to admin MySQL, or is there a plugin that makes things more integrated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the [Netbeans database integration](http://netbeans.org/features/ide/database.html), it has several useful features:

- completion
- insert/delete/edit tables in the IDE
- connect any database (I use it with MySQL, Oracle and hsqldb)

Comment: that looks like what I am after, very cool.  BTW, you use netbeans at work? I thought everyone uses Eclipse!  Are you on a windows computer or mac?

Comment: so I just install mysql seperately or will netbeans plugin install the server also?

Comment: you must install mysql (on any other DBMS) separately!

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that this "integration" is so important. What are you integrating? It's just another perspective rather than ALT+TAB.

For MySQL I use MySQL Administrator and MySQL Query Browser. It's just a matter of UI and provided functionality preference. It's not a matter of being a plugin or not.

Answer (score 4):

NetBeans has very good [database support](http://netbeans.org/features/ide/database.html), including [MySQL](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html). So there is no need for an external admin tool if you are using NetBeans IMO.

In Eclipse, the database support that you get with the [Eclipse Data Tools Platform (DTP)](http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/) is more "Query" oriented, not really "admin" oriented and you won't get wizards to create tables and so on. If this is what you're looking for, then you may need an external tool when using Eclipse (phpmyadmin, Toad, MySQL admin tool, whatever).

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse you may use [DBViewer](http://www.ne.jp/asahi/zigen/home/plugin/dbviewer/about_en.html).
It's the best DB plugin for Eclipse (IMHO)

Answer (score 0):

I use MySQL-Front

Answer (score 0):

The first thing i did  was learn to use the native CLI tools for mysql. There are quite a few, mysql itself, mysladmin, mysqldump, mysqlimport etc. These are very powerful and have many more options than any GUI i have ever seen. You do not need to learn all the commands but running, say, mysqladmin and looking at the options will give you an overview of what is there.

The second thing to do is to write some scripts at the CLI to do the normal everyday things you want. These are like a set of tools that you can carry around and adapt as circumstances dictate.

The beauty of doing the two above items means you can work on any system with MySQL on it regardless of OS or GUI's. It means you can work remotely over slow networks and still get stuff done.

After that GUI's and integrated tool are OK and often quicker in visual terms for looking at details. phpmyadmin is good as it will go on most systems. Never really tried the plugins with Eclipse, used the MySQL GUI tools but find them flaky, however i use a Mac so that might be a factor. If you use Mac then Sequel Pro is a usefull tool.